# How do I position two elements side by side surrounded by a border?

Tags: html, css

I have one `<div>` element with two `<ul>` elements inside. I want to put them side by side but when I do that, the `<ul>` elements appear outside of the section border. I'm working on a project for a fake Job application showing off some abilities (most I don't possess) for some reason. I want to have the two elements appear inside of the border. I'm new to CSS and not sure about 'child' or 'sibling' elements either.

CSS:

```
ul {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12pt;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

ul p {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.section {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="section">
  <h1>My Abilities</h1>
  <ul>
    <ul>
      <p>Hacking</p>
      <li>Disable Alarms</li>
      <li>Access Security Cameras</li>
      <li>Delay Camera and Alarm response time</li>
      <li>Disable Guard Pagers</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <p>Gunmanship</p>
      <li>Able to handle any type of weapon, big or small</li>
      <li>Resourcefull with ammo</li>
      <li>Deadshot</li>
      <li>Can play many roles, from Heavy to Stealth</li>
      <li>Great Getaway driver</li>
      <li>Fast reloader with little recoil</li>
      <li>Excellent at training others</li>
      <li>Military grade training</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make these changes to these two lines in your code:

```
ul {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12pt;
    /*float: left;*/ /* delete this line */
    display: inline-table; /* change this to inline-table */
}
```

And then remove the outer `<ul>` tags as shown in the below complete code:

Complete Code:

CSS:

```
ul {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12pt;
    display: inline-table;
}

ul p {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.section {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
} 
.section h1 {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="section">
        <h1>My Abilities</h1> 
            <ul>
                <p>Hacking</p>
                <li>Disable Alarms</li>
                <li>Access Security Cameras</li>
                <li>Delay Camera and Alarm response time</li>
                <li>Disable Guard Pagers</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <p>Gunmanship</p>
                <li>Able to handle any type of weapon, big or small</li>
                <li>Resourcefull with ammo</li>
                <li>Deadshot</li>
                <li>Can play many roles, from Heavy to Stealth</li>
                <li>Great Getaway driver</li>
                <li>Fast reloader with little recoil</li>
                <li>Excellent at training others</li>
                <li>Military grade training</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: may also want to add ```vertical-align: top;``` to the ul tag

Answer (score 0):

This is just another alternative whether you can use bootstrap.

```css
ul {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12pt;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

ul p {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.section {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
} 

h1{
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="content section">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>My Abilities</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <ul>
                <p>Hacking</p>
                <li>Disable Alarms</li>
                <li>Access Security Cameras</li>
                <li>Delay Camera and Alarm response time</li>
                <li>Disable Guard Pagers</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <ul>
                <p>Gunmanship</p>
                <li>Able to handle any type of weapon, big or small</li>
                <li>Resourcefull with ammo</li>
                <li>Deadshot</li>
                <li>Can play many roles, from Heavy to Stealth</li>
                <li>Great Getaway driver</li>
                <li>Fast reloader with little recoil</li>
                <li>Excellent at training others</li>
                <li>Military grade training</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```